# Constants over multiple servers

Tags: mysql, authentication, refactoring, constants, credentials

The question is, how to update a constant? This sounds like a stupid question, but let's look at the background of my issue:

## Background

I manage a network of servers, which includes a MySQL server, multiple HTTP servers, and a Minecraft server (a self-hosted server that gamers who have installed Minecraft can connect to and play together). All of the user-end services (HTTP servers, Minecraft server, user apps) are directly or indirectly related to the MySQL server. The MySQL database stores different data for each player account, for example, the online/offline status of players, etc.

In programming, constants are used to create a general reference to a value that will not change across a runtime. Especially, for software-internal identifiers, such as data flags, bitmasks, etc. In my case, I also use constants to store specific data, such as the MySQL server's address and other credentials. So when I want to change the server address, I only need to modify them from one point, for example, an internal `constants.php` of the server.

## Problem

1. When I migrate my MySQL database to another host or change password, I have to update the details on every server. It is not possible to create a centralized data provider that provides the server address, because the MySQL server itself is the centralized data provider. That means, every time I change the value, I must update all servers. I must also maintain a very private and local list (probably has to be written down on a memo and stick it on my computer!) of all these places, because it is really hard to locate all these references. So, my question is, is there a better way of management that allows me to change the values from one place? Note that the servers are on different hosts, so it is not possible to put it in a local file, and it doesn't sound reasonable to create a centralized data provider (call it *password provider*) to provide access of the real centralized data provider (MySQL) either, since if I have the need to change the MySQL database details, I have the same need to change the password provider details as well.
2. This is less a concern. but since it is a similar question, I am putting it down here too. I use integer bitmasks to store player ranks. For example, if the player is a VIP, he has a `0x01` flag, and if the player is a moderator, he has a `0x10` flag, and `0x11` if both VIP and moderator, vice versa. I want to refactor the bitmask values as well, but it would be great trouble, because I need to shut down all servers and update the MySQL values, update constants on every server, then restart all servers, to avoid potential security vulnerability in the period of updating. Is there a more convenient way to do that?

This is a network management question too, but I consider it more programming-related.

Comment: One simple answer to the first question is to use the DNS.  That is, create an address record for your MySQL server within a domain that you administer, e.g. `rdbms.example.com`, and then the other machines need only use that hostname to connect.  Should the MySQL server change addresses, you need only update the DNS.  Security credentials are by their very nature more difficult to distribute—but they need only be stored in one place on each machine, readable by any process that requires them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We are talking about **deployment system**. For example we can use
   capistrano: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano. We need to
   save constants.php to git and create task in capistrano for deploy
   this file to each server. I use this tool for deploying of projects which are one of the 50 busiest sites of the Russian segment of the Internet:)
2. We are talking about **data migration**. So there are several ways. Some of them with downtimes and some not (sometimes it depends on the situation).

Data migration without downtime:

1. modify your app so it will understand old variant of players bitmask
   and new one
2. deploy modified app
3. update bitmask into your databases
4. modify your app so it will understand only new variant of bitmasks
5. deploy modified app